# Asp.net webforms with Entity Framework 6 Update page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, entity-framework-6

I'm working with asp.net webforms and I'm a beginner with Entity Framework. I need to know how to make an update page and send data from page to a method (binding) without having to bind field by field and save changes.

Suppose I have this class :

```
public class Fiche
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string mrmme  { get; set; }
    public string nometprenom { get; set; }
    public string adresse { get; set; }
    public string ville { get; set; }
    public string cp { get; set; }
    public string tele { get; set; }
    public string portable { get; set; }
    public string datenaissance { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string situation { get; set; }
    public string profession { get; set; }

    #region // Santé & Prévoyance
    public string typesp { get; set; }
    public string nombresassures { get; set; }
    public string regime { get; set; }
    public string nbrenfants { get; set; }
    public string mutuelleactuelle { get; set; }
    public string tarifcontrat { get; set; }
    public string niveaugaranties { get; set; }
    public string mutuelle { get; set; }
    #endregion 

    public string Createdbynom { 
        get {
            return Data.Db.Users.Find(Createdby).nom;
        }
    }

    public string Affectedtonom
    {
        get
        {
            return Data.Db.Users.Find(Affectedto).nom;
        }
    }

    public ICollection<Contrat> Contrats { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Commentaire> Commentaires { get; set; }

    public string Createdby { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Createdby")]
    public ApplicationUser createuser { get; set; }

    public string Affectedto { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Affectedto")]
    public ApplicationUser affetcteduser { get; set; }
}
```

I have lot of fields if I want to create a form to update this model. I need to create textbox for every field and when I click "submit" button, I need to get every value from every textbox and bind to model and call `SaveChnages`?

Is this the only way in webforms to update data a database?

Is there any way to binding data from my form to my update method?

Comment: Check out: https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/asp-net-4-5-web-forms-features-model-binding

Comment: But this is for binding data inside gridview i neef binding between form contains textbox and submit method

Comment: This is **NOT** only for gridview - you can also bind a `FormView` or a `DetailView` with several textboxes, checkboxes, etc. to a model class